# Connection refused on python sockets (port is open, I can connect with nc)

Tags: python, sockets, telnetlib

So for personal reasons, I want to connect to a socket I create via telnetlib, I can connect to it from netcat but when I try from python it refuses the connection.

```
tn.write(b"/usr/bin/nc -l -p 3333 -e /bin/sh\n")
print("netcat listening on 3333 on target, trying to connect")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((tn.host, 3333))
s.send('ls')
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

If I can connect to it via netcat (by putting for example and infinite loop after tn.write())

Comment: should this really be `/bin/sh<backquote>` as in the code you've shown?

Comment: that's not the problem if I run /usr/bin/nc -l -p 3333 -e /bin/sh on the remote machine I can connect to it via netcat

Comment: You might note that the command you start from python has a backquote at the end according to the code you've shown while the command you run on the remote machine does not.

Comment: That was a typo when copying to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a classic [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition):

The packet containing the command to start an `nc` is sent at only nanoseconds before the connection request (TCP SYN packet) of `s.connect`. It can even happen that the `SYN` gets to the remote host before the command to start `nc`.

You need to add proper synchronization. From the code you have shown, there is really no need to use two channels in the first place, so why not send the `ls` via the existing telnet channel to the remote host?

If you absolutely must use a second channel, try one of these options:

- Add `import time` and `time.sleep(5)` just before calling `s.connect`. That way, the connection attempt will be deferred by 5 seconds. However, in general, there's no guarantee that 5 seconds is enough.
- Send an additional command to [wait for the port to be taken](https://github.com/phihag/check_port_free/blob/master/check_port_free.py), as a sign that nc is ready.
- Retry multiple times (and wait in between).

Also note that your code has three different security vulnerabilities:

1. You are using telnetlib, which neither ensures confidentiality nor integrity of commands, output and passwords. Use ssh instead.
2. You are connecting to port 3333 in plain, which neither ensures confidentiality nor integrity of commands and output. Use ssh instead.
3. In between nc starting and your program connecting to it, anyone can connect to port 3333 and run arbitrary commands. Use ssh instead.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I managed to fix it, I know it has security vulnerabilities but I'm doing this for research purposes. Thanks again!